# SwiftUI - Expanding the main grid horizontally pushes my other views offscreen

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am working on an iPhone app using SwiftUI. The main grid uses HStacks nested inside a VStack. The number of columns will be variable on initialization, but fixed thereafter. The number of rows is completely dynamic. When the grid expands beyond the width or height of the screen it pushes the other views out of the way.

I would like it to just expand rightward (on initialization) and downward (dynamically) offscreen and behind the other views. I tried putting everything in a ZStack and setting their zindices, but that didn't work. Is there any way to do this or do I need a new approach?

```
//
//  GameView.swift
//  Scoreboard
//
//  Created by user926153 on 8/21/20.
//  Copyright Â© 2020 user926153. All rights reserved.
//
//
//

/*
 This uses the TrackableScrollView as created by Max Natchanon here:
https://medium.com/@maxnatchanon/swiftui-how-to-get-content-offset-from-scrollview-5ce1f84603ec
 */

import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [CGFloat]
    
    static var defaultValue: [CGFloat] = [0]
    
    static func reduce(value: inout [CGFloat], nextValue: () -> [CGFloat]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}

struct TrackableScrollView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let axes: Axis.Set
    let showIndicators: Bool
    @Binding var contentOffset: CGFloat
    let content: Content
    
    init(_ axes: Axis.Set = .vertical, showIndicators: Bool = true, contentOffset: Binding<CGFloat>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.axes = axes
        self.showIndicators = showIndicators
        self._contentOffset = contentOffset
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { outsideProxy in
        ScrollView(self.axes, showsIndicators: self.showIndicators) {
            ZStack(alignment: self.axes == .vertical ? .top : .leading) {
                GeometryReader { insideProxy in
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: [self.calculateContentOffset(fromOutsideProxy: outsideProxy, insideProxy: insideProxy)])
                        // Send value to the parent
                }
                VStack {
                    self.content
                }
            }
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
            self.contentOffset = value[0]
        }
        // Get the value then assign to offset binding
    }
}
    
    private func calculateContentOffset(fromOutsideProxy outsideProxy: GeometryProxy, insideProxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        if axes == .vertical {
            return (outsideProxy.frame(in: .global).minY - insideProxy.frame(in: .global).minY) * -1
        } else {
            return (outsideProxy.frame(in: .global).minX - insideProxy.frame(in: .global).minX) * -1
        }
    }
}

struct GameView: View {
    let row_label_offset: CGFloat = 80
    let col_width: CGFloat = 75
    let row_height: CGFloat = 50
    
    @ObservedObject var settings: GameSettings
    @State var round_number: Int = 1
    @State var scores: [[Int]] = [[0, 0, 0, 0]]
    @State var column_offset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var row_offset: CGFloat = 0
    
    private func AddRound() {
        self.round_number += 1
        self.scores.append([0, 0, 0, 0])
    }
    
    private func DeleteRound(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        // NOTE: also have to delete round from score array
        self.round_number -= 1
        self.scores.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Text("Title")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("subtitle")
            }
            .border(Color.black)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.AddRound()
                    }) {
                        Text("New round +")
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    }
                    .frame(width: self.row_label_offset, height: self.row_height)
                    
                    TrackableScrollView(.horizontal, showIndicators: false, contentOffset: $column_offset) {
                        HStack {
                            ForEach((1...7), id: \.self) {
                                Text("Player \($0)\n  total")
                                .frame(width: self.col_width, height: self.row_height)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .border(Color.red)
                }
                
                
                HStack {
                    TrackableScrollView(.vertical, showIndicators: false, contentOffset: $row_offset) {
                        
                        ForEach((1...self.round_number), id: \.self) { round in
                            Text("Round \(round)")
                            .frame(width: self.col_width, height: self.row_height)
                        }
                    }
                    .border(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: self.row_label_offset)
                    
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(self.scores, id: \.self) { round_score in
                            HStack {
                                ForEach(round_score, id: \.self) { score in
                                    Text("\(score)")
                                    .frame(width: self.col_width, height: self.row_height)
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .offset(x: self.column_offset, y: self.row_offset)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
                .border(Color.blue)
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Text("Finish Game")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG

struct GameView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        GameView(settings: GameSettings())
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: So when you expand the main grid offscreen by adding 15 or so new rows it doesn't affect the other views? It just expands downward and scrolls as normal? I am not at my mac but I don't think I am using Xcode 12b5.

Comment: Got it - I did not add 15+ rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fixed part - to avoid layout corruption you have to move dynamic part *out-of-current-layout*, eg. in overlay of empty space area. Also some minor fixes added, like clipping and alignment.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
    HStack {
        TrackableScrollView(.vertical, showIndicators: false, contentOffset: $row_offset) {

            ForEach((1...self.round_number), id: \.self) { round in
                Text("Round \(round)")
                .frame(width: self.col_width, height: self.row_height)
            }
        }
        .border(Color.black)
        .frame(width: self.row_label_offset)

        Color.clear.overlay (      // << from here !!
            VStack {
                ForEach(self.scores, id: \.self) { round_score in
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(round_score, id: \.self) { score in
                            Text("\(score)")
                            .frame(width: self.col_width, height: self.row_height)
                        }

                    }
                }

                Spacer()
            }
            .offset(x: self.column_offset, y: self.row_offset)
        , alignment: .topLeading)
        .clipped()
    }
    .border(Color.blue)
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much. I don't quite understand why this worked though. So the overlay is a new view that is on top of the other views?